# How to use non-minified js (e.g. jQuery) for debugging/development?

Tags: 8, javascript

### Background

Drupal core contains some 3rd party javascript libraries, among them jQuery. Typically such libraries are available as un-minified and minified versions. A minified js file *can* have a reference to a source map via `sourceMappingURL`, which can be used by the browser developer tools to show the original source.

Since https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1341792, js files like jQuery are shipped as a minified version.

In https://www.drupal.org/project/devel/issues/2471919, it was considered to add an option in devel to send the un-minified version instead. This was discarded because we can use source maps.

The minified `jQuery.min.js` used to have a `sourceMappingURL` reference, but this is gone in newer versions.

I also found some issues talking about warnings and errors from files with `sourceMappingURL`, if the referenced source map is missing. But I don't know if these are related.

### Problem

There seems to be no way (besides hackery) to see the original js file (e.g. original jQuery.js) for debugging in the browser.

*EDIT: The browser can prettify the js, but it cannot un-minify the variable names or restore comments. So I do not consider this a sufficient solution. I should have mentioned this directly.*

### Question

Am I missing something? Is there a hidden option or contrib solution to make the source maps work, or to use the un-minified jquery.js for debugging during development?

(depending on the answer, I might open an issue on drupal.org)

Comment: [Make JavaScript Look Pretty | Chrome DevTools | Google Developers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/pretty-print&ved=2ahUKEwiz5caM6oPsAhWGqp4KHdy2CnUQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1Vv2NUq2nq2aqEyULZA3fi&cshid=1601020723586)

Comment: @NoSssweat But this does not un-minify the variable names.