# Add event listener to modal close

Tags: modal-dialogs

In Drupal we can open a modal is two ways, either with HTML:

```
<a class="use-ajax profile-page-link" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/1" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:800}">Open Modal</a>
```

Or with JS:

```
let ajaxSettings = {
  url: 'node/1',
  dialogType: 'modal',
  dialog: { width: 800 },
};
let ajaxObject = Drupal.ajax(ajaxSettings);
ajaxObject.execute();
```

Once the modal is open I would like to attach an event to the close button so I can drop a cookie on the close event to show the visitor has seen the modal and not show it to them again.

The close button has the class `ui-dialog-titlebar-close` but this is added after the initial page load so to attach an event we would need a dynamic click handler such as:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function() {
    alert('close button was clicked 2');
});
```

However this event never fires. [This ctools issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools/issues/826786) mentions the same thing and has a solution involving binding to the `CToolsCloseModalBehaviors` event, however that was 6 years ago and I'm using D9 with no ctools so need to find a new solution.

When I inspect the attached events on the close button I can see `jquery.ui/ui/widget-min.js` `r()` and an anonymous function in `jquery.min.js`. Using non minified vs would help but [not sure how to do that?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296963/how-to-use-non-minified-js-e-g-jquery-for-debugging-development)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In core dialog.js code I've found a following lines of code.

```
$(window).trigger('dialog:afterclose', [dialog, $element]);
```

and

```
$(window).trigger('dialog:beforeclose', [dialog, $element]);
```

Means that it is possible to assign event listener to these events using the following code sample:

```
$(window).on('dialog:afterclose', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

P.S. Just don't forget to put it into Drupal behaviors and use .once to ensure that event listeners won't attach multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The clue was seeing the Drupal's modal just uses jquery widgets. So a simple Google for "jquery widget close event" lead me to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/172000/967168).

So the solution is:

```
$('#drupal-modal').on('dialogclose', function(event) {
    alert('closed');
});
```